# Upgrade pip inside azure function

Tags: python, azure, pip

I am deploying azure function from VS Code and it fails with warning that my pip version is out of date.

I know that the real error with suds-jurko but I feel like the issue will be resolved once I update pip. But that pip is different from my local testing one so how do i tell it to update?

Output:

```
6:08:05 am wwxreportgenerator: Starting deployment...
6:08:09 am wwxreportgenerator: Creating zip package...
6:08:10 am wwxreportgenerator: Zip package size: 27.3 kB
6:08:14 am wwxreportgenerator: Updating submodules.
6:08:15 am wwxreportgenerator: Preparing deployment for commit id '73cfe23be7'.
6:08:15 am wwxreportgenerator: Repository path is /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
6:08:15 am wwxreportgenerator: Running oryx build...
6:08:15 am wwxreportgenerator: Command: oryx build /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted -o /home/site/wwwroot --platform python --platform-version 3.8 -p packagedir=.python_packages/lib/site-packages
6:08:16 am wwxreportgenerator: Operation performed by Microsoft Oryx, https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx
6:08:16 am wwxreportgenerator: You can report issues at https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx/issues
6:08:16 am wwxreportgenerator: Oryx Version: 0.2.20201015.1, Commit: 1a35fbce482b20b71290f3a837a3469803ce4b44, ReleaseTagName: 20201015.1
6:08:16 am wwxreportgenerator: Build Operation ID: |+1cUmaYelrQ=.d9749a6_
6:08:16 am wwxreportgenerator: Repository Commit : 73cfe23be7d043ecbcd75e94c5c51004
6:08:16 am wwxreportgenerator: Detecting platforms...
6:08:18 am wwxreportgenerator: Detected following platforms:
6:08:18 am wwxreportgenerator:   python: 3.8.12
6:08:18 am wwxreportgenerator: Version '3.8.12' of platform 'python' is not installed. Generating script to install it...
6:08:19 am wwxreportgenerator: Source directory     : /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
6:08:19 am wwxreportgenerator: Destination directory: /home/site/wwwroot
6:08:19 am wwxreportgenerator: Downloading and extracting 'python' version '3.8.12' to '/tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.8.12'...
6:08:32 am wwxreportgenerator: Downloaded in 13 sec(s).
6:08:32 am wwxreportgenerator: Verifying checksum...
6:08:32 am wwxreportgenerator: Extracting contents...
6:08:35 am wwxreportgenerator: Done in 16 sec(s).
6:08:35 am wwxreportgenerator: Python Version: /tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.8.12/bin/python3.8
6:08:35 am wwxreportgenerator: Running pip install...
6:08:36 am wwxreportgenerator: [19:08:36+0000] Collecting azure-functions
6:08:36 am wwxreportgenerator: [19:08:36+0000]   Downloading azure_functions-1.10.1-py3-none-any.whl (198 kB)
6:08:36 am wwxreportgenerator: [19:08:36+0000] Collecting azure-cosmos
6:08:36 am wwxreportgenerator: [19:08:36+0000]   Downloading azure_cosmos-4.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (136 kB)
6:08:36 am wwxreportgenerator: [19:08:36+0000] Collecting azure-storage-blob==2.1.0
6:08:36 am wwxreportgenerator: [19:08:36+0000]   Downloading azure_storage_blob-2.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (88 kB)
6:08:37 am wwxreportgenerator: [19:08:37+0000] Collecting sqlalchemy
6:08:37 am wwxreportgenerator: [19:08:37+0000]   Downloading SQLAlchemy-1.4.32-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (1.6 MB)
6:08:37 am wwxreportgenerator: [19:08:37+0000] Collecting jinja2
6:08:38 am wwxreportgenerator: [19:08:38+0000]   Downloading Jinja2-3.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (132 kB)
6:08:38 am wwxreportgenerator: [19:08:38+0000] Collecting pyodbc
6:08:38 am wwxreportgenerator: [19:08:38+0000]   Downloading pyodbc-4.0.32.tar.gz (280 kB)
6:08:38 am wwxreportgenerator: [19:08:38+0000] Collecting requests
6:08:38 am wwxreportgenerator: [19:08:38+0000]   Downloading requests-2.27.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (63 kB)
6:08:39 am wwxreportgenerator: [19:08:39+0000] Collecting pandas
6:08:39 am wwxreportgenerator: [19:08:39+0000]   Downloading pandas-1.4.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (11.7 MB)
6:08:39 am wwxreportgenerator: [19:08:39+0000] Collecting seaborn
6:08:39 am wwxreportgenerator: [19:08:39+0000]   Downloading seaborn-0.11.2-py3-none-any.whl (292 kB)
6:08:39 am wwxreportgenerator: [19:08:39+0000] Collecting suds-jurko
6:08:39 am wwxreportgenerator: [19:08:39+0000]   Downloading suds-jurko-0.6.tar.bz2 (143 kB)
6:08:40 am wwxreportgenerator:     ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
6:08:40 am wwxreportgenerator:      command: /tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.8.12/bin/python3.8 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-dgbxji9z/suds-jurko/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-dgbxji9z/suds-jurko/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r
6:08:40 am wwxreportgenerator: '"'"', '"'"'
6:08:40 am wwxreportgenerator: '"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-anhns_8n
6:08:40 am wwxreportgenerator:          cwd: /tmp/pip-install-dgbxji9z/suds-jurko/
6:08:40 am wwxreportgenerator:     Complete output (1 lines):
6:08:40 am wwxreportgenerator:     error in suds-jurko setup command: use_2to3 is invalid.
6:08:40 am wwxreportgenerator:     ----------------------------------------
6:08:40 am wwxreportgenerator: ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
6:08:40 am wwxreportgenerator: WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.3; however, version 22.0.4 is available.
6:08:40 am wwxreportgenerator: You should consider upgrading via the '/tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.8.12/bin/python3.8 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
6:08:40 am wwxreportgenerator: Done in 5 sec(s).
6:08:42 am wwxreportgenerator: ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
6:08:42 am wwxreportgenerator:      command: /tmp/oryx/platforms/python/3.8.12/bin/python3.8 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-dgbxji9z/suds-jurko/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-dgbxji9z/suds-jurko/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r
6:08:42 am wwxreportgenerator: '"'"', '"'"'
6:08:42 am wwxreportgenerator: '"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-anhns_8n
6:08:42 am wwxreportgenerator: /opt/Kudu/Scripts/starter.sh oryx build /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted -o /home/site/wwwroot --platform python --platform-version 3.8 -p packagedir=.python_packages/lib/site-packages
6:08:48 am wwxreportgenerator: Deployment failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this `error in suds-jurko setup command: use_2to3 is invalid`, you can try the following ways:

1. Install `v58.0.0` of `setuptools`:

```
pip install 'setuptools==58.0.0'
```

2. To avoid getting download of different version of the same package:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt --use-deprecated=legacy-resolver
```

References: [error in suds-jurko setup command: use_2to3 is invalid](https://github.com/andersinno/suds-jurko/issues/6)
, [Pip downloads lots of different versions of the same package](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9922) and [ERROR in suds-jurko setup command" during deployment of Azure Function App for Python 3.9](https://github.com/microsoft/Oryx/issues/1134)